# Mediaplayer when coming back to activity

Tags: java, android

This is my onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    try{
    if(m.isPlaying()){
        m.pause();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

This is my onStop:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    try{
    if(m!=null){
        m.stop();
        m.release();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

And this is my onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    try{
        if (m == null) {
                m.reset();
                m = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu);
                m.start();
        }
        else{
            m.start();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

There is a mediaplayer on my activity that plays, My goal is that when a new activity opens it will stop, and when there is a back press the music will reset and start playing all over again. This code only stops the music on new activity, when I come back there is no music. Why?

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` in catch block probably getting Exception

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it gives illegalstateexception

Comment: If this is the code you are actually running, it should always give a `NullPointerException`. You check `m == null`, then proceed to call `m.reset()` even though it is most assuredly null.

Comment: hmm, then `m != null` in his case. So he would have an released m only and calling start on it.

Comment: @SatelliteSD m!=null worked, but I'm now very confused, only when I stated m=new Mediaplayer(); after the m!=null it worked, but before that it also worked when I did that on oncreate without stating m=new Mediaplayer(); how come there it worked and here it doesnt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (m == null) {
     m.reset();
     m = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu);
     m.start();
 }
```

here you are starting an uninitialised MediaPlayer instance. You need to prepare it first before calling `start()`. Therefore you should get an `IllegalStateException`.
[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) is a statediagram for reference.

Comment: So how come it works when I first go in the app.. this is weird. also I prepared it and it still wont work

Comment: depends on your `onCreate` which is not called when only resuming.

Comment: I've never stated m=new MediaPlayer(); and yet it worked, how come?

Comment: probably `m = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu);` returns an instance of MediaPlayer and you have assigned it to `m`?

Comment: But I did that also in on resume, and there it didnt work only until I wrote m=new Mediaplayer(); this is odd, I dont understand mediaplayers.

Comment: debug and count mediaplayer instances and make sure you are releasing them as soon they are not needed.